# How to parse string date in to timestamp or date

Tags: java

```
String fromDate = "12-Oct-2011 14:23:47";
SimpleDateFormat sdf1 = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-mm-dd");   
java.util.Date fdate  = sdf1.parse(fromDate);
```

It gives error

> java.parseException: unpasable date:"12-Oct-2011 14:23:47"

I want to parse string into date.

Answer (score 4):

Of course: you're trying to parse `12-Oct-2011` with the pattern `yyyy-mm-dd`. This pattern means "the year on 4 digits, followed by minutes on 2 digits, followed by the day on two digits".

See the [javadoc of `SimpleDateFormat`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) to understand how a pattern must be composed. In your case, it should be `dd-MMM-yyyy HH:mm:ss`.